# How to add context to chat-gpt twilio customer service bot?

Tags: node.js, twilio, openai-api, langchain, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to implement langchain to this call-gpt repo so that I can get a twilio phone number to answer company specific questions. How would I go about this?

https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/call-gpt-twilio#Configure-your-environment (tutorial used to get twilio gpt number to work)
https://github.com/kuschanton/call-gpt (call-gpt repo)
https://github.com/techleadhd/chatgpt-retrieval/tree/main (script for retrieving files to use for chatgpt context) (something i found on the side that might help)

Not sure how to go about it.